# Can i use a dictionary with a user defined function?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, tkinter

I'm trying to make a periodic table(a simple one) in which I can enter the atomic number of an element and it will give details of the element. I've created the window and labels but the problem is with button. I'm trying to use dictionary with the button function . Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?Thanks

```
     from Tkinter import *

    """p={}
    p={"1":["hydrogen",'group 1','Electronic configuration- 1s1'] ,
       "2":["helium",'group 18','Electronic configuration- 1s2'],
       "3":["lithium",'group 1','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s1'],
       "4":["beryllium",'group 2','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2'],
       "5":["boron",'group 13','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2 2p1'],
       "6":["carbon",'group 14','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2 2p2'],
       "7":["nitrogen",'group 15','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2 2p3'],
       "8":["oxygen",'group 16','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2 2p4'],
       "9":["fluorine",'group 17','Electronic configuration- [He] 2s2 2p5'],
       "10":["neon",'group 18','Electroni?c configuration- [He] 2s2 2p6'],
         }
       def search():
         x=raw_input('enter the atomic no. of the element you wanna search')
         for i in x:
            if i==x:
              print p[i]
            else:
               break
       search()


         def search():
            c=Label(ptable,text='Help me ',fg='blue',bg='red',font= ('Helpme',14)).place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8, anchor=S) 




    ptable=Tk()
    ptable.geometry('550x250+100+50')
    ptable.title('Periodic Table')
    ptable.config(background='red') # we can use either 'config' or   'configure', farak nin pdega


    f=StringVar()




    a=Label(ptable,text='My Periodic table', fg='blue',font=('My Periodic  table',16,'bold'),bg='red').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.05, anchor=CENTER)
    b=Label(ptable,text='Enter atomic number of the element',bg='red',font= ('Enter atomic number of the element',13,'bold')).place(relx=0,rely=0.3,  anchor=W)


    x=Entry(ptable,textvariable=f).place(relx=0.9, rely=0.3, anchor=E)



    button=Button(ptable,text='FIND OUT!',command=search).place(relx=0.5, rely= 0.6 , anchor=S)






    ptable.mainloop()
```

and while you're at it can u also tell me how to add an image in this program if i wanted to? thanks ^^

Comment: "and while you're at it..." will not be well received. Ask another separate question. Also what's with the `"""` at the beginning?

Comment: Also search() has been declared twice.  A link to a tutorial on dictionaries http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm  More tutorials at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: Woops, see response below.

Answer (score 0):

This following will not always work.  Add a print statement for numbers greater than 9 to see for yourself. Also do not use "i", "l", or "o" as single character names as they can look like numbers.

```
    for i in x:
        if i==x:
```

Comment: @alex hall 
That's because initially i wanted the """ program to be the reference for the command button but it didn't turn out well so instead of running it and getting an error i made it a comment and see what was wrong in the whole program . That's  why i asked here ^^